# Even and odd permutations intersect at 1 number?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

Let $\pi\in S_n$ for $n=3$ be a permutation.
We may think of $\pi$ as entries $(i,\pi(i))_{1\le i\le 3}$ of a 3-by-3 matrix.

One claims that if $\pi_1$ is an odd permutation and $\pi_2$ is an even permutation, then they intersect at exactly one entry, i.e., there is exactly one $i$ such that $\pi_1(i)=\pi_2(i)$.

I know this is true because I know what all the odd and even permutations look like when $n=3$ and check all the nine possibilities. But I am wondering is it possible to prove it abstractly? And is it true when $n$ is a larger odd number?

Comment: The odd permutations consists of transpositions.  The even ones are the identity and $3-$cycles.  The identity matches a transposition at the common fixed point.  The cycle must match half of the transposition.

Comment: What do you mean by "meet at"?

Comment: Note: I am interpreting the question the question as requiring that there be some $i\in \{1,2,3\}$ such that $\pi_1(i)=\pi_2(i)$.  Please clarify your intent.  With that interpretation, if the odd transposition takes $i$ to $j$ then either the even cycle either takes $i$ to $j$ (in which case we are done) or it takes $i$ to $k$ in which case it must take $j$ to $i$ and again we are done.

Comment: It means "intersecting". I revised the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rephrase the question:

We want to show that if $\pi_1$ is an odd permutation and $\pi_2$ is an even permutation of the sequence $(1,2,3)$ then there is exactly one integer $i$ such that $1 \leq i \leq 3$ and $\pi_1(i) = \pi_2(i)$.

Observe that every permutation is invertible, so $\pi_1(i) = \pi_2(i)$
if and only if $\pi_1^{-1}(\pi_2(i)) = i$.
So the number of entries at which $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ "meet" is equal to the number of fixed points of $\pi_1^{-1}\pi_2$, that is, the number of elements of the sequence that are left in place by $\pi_1^{-1}\pi_2$.

Further, since $\pi_1$ is odd, $\pi_1^{-1}$ is odd, and since $\pi_1^{-1}$ is odd and $\pi_2$ is even, $\pi_1^{-1}\pi_2$ is odd.

Moreover, any odd permutation can be written as $\pi_1^{-1}\pi_2$ where $\pi_1$ is odd and $\pi_2$ is even. So we're basically asking what number of fixed points an odd permutation can have.

For $S_3$, the odd permutations are precisely the single transpositions.
Each single transposition leaves one element fixed and swaps the other two elements,
so we always have one fixed point. QED.

---

Now let's consider $S_5$. Odd permutations include any single transposition,
any four-cycle such as $(1 2 3 4)$,
and permutations such as $(123)(45)$, which move all elements.
So we can have three fixed points, one fixed point, or no fixed points.
We cannot have five fixed points (the identity is even), four fixed points (no permutation can move exactly one element), or two fixed points;
two fixed points implies three elements participating in a permutation of three elements with no fixed points, which we already know cannot be an odd permutation.

So for $S_5$ the number of points at which and odd and even permutation "meet" can be $0$, $1$, or $3$.

For $S_7$, odd permutations include single transpositions, four-cycles, permutations such as $(123)(45)$, six-cycles, and permutations such as $(12345)(67)$., among others.
These leave (respectively) $5$, $3$, $2$, $1$, and $0$ elements fixed.
Again the identity is even, no permutation moves only one element, and any permutation that moves exactly three elements is even, so $7$, $6$, and $4$ fixed points are impossible for an odd permutation.
Therefore the number of points at which and odd and even permutation "meet" can be $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, or $5$.

Generalizing this for any odd $n$, we can find odd permutations that leave $k$ fixed elements for any $k$ in the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$ **except**
$k = n$, $k = n - 1$, and $k = n - 3$.

In the case $n = 3$ it just happens that those three exceptions leave only $k = 1$ as a possible number of fixed points.